# Regular expression which excludes all kinds of URL

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I could find various examples of regular expression regarding http / protocols and urls but still I could not find the exact regular expression which can avoid all kinds of url or protocols.

My aim is to not allow any kind of url in a text box ( http://example.com, https://example.com, www.example.com , http://example.in etc....) . I have tried multiple regular expression but cud not get the proper one...

I have to just add this regular expression as a property which will be than executed by already created java class of regular expression.

Gaurav

Comment: find a regex to match all the urls. the put that regex inside negative lookahead `^(?!.*regex).*`

Comment: The *"exact regular expression"* to match *"all kinds of urls and protocols"* is a couple of thousands characters long.

Comment: @axiac you can just put your answer specific to the urls I have listed above

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have put the regex in negative lookahead but that seems not to be working 
^(?!.*/(?:(https?:\/\/)|\1?www\.)\w+\.\w{2,5}/).*

Answer (score 0):

From a bit of research I realised that it is hard to do a foolproof one for all the possible URLs. [This website](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) has regex which matches many website URLs. What you can do is use the complement of that regex.

Answer (score 0):

> @AvinashRaj I have put the regex in negative lookahead but that seems not to be working `^(?!.*/(?:(https?:\/\/)|\1?www\.)\w+\.\w{2,5}/).*`

You just need to remove the regex delimiters.

```
^(?!.*(?:(https?:\/\/)|\1?www\.)\w+\.\w{2,5}).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR3uK6/1)